# Modal plugin seems to break when AJAX success is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a form that is located in a modal. The modal comes from a plugin found [here](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal). I am submitting the data in this form via an AJAX call and then after the data is successfully processed, a DIV on my main page is refreshed inside the AJAX success section.

Here is my Modal & Form code:

```
<!--- Link to open the modal to add a new dasboard link --->
     <div id="DashboardLinks" style="display:none;">
     <h3>Add a new dashboard link:</h3>
     <form id="add_dashboard_links">
        <table width="100%" id="dashboard_table" border="0" cellpadding="5">

          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Link Description:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="link_description" id="link_description" required="yes" message="Please enter the Link Description"/></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Link URL:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="link_url" id="link_url" required="yes" validate="url" message="Please enter the Link URL with http:// -or- https://"/></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Link Notes:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><textarea id="notes" name="notes" cols="" rows="">&nbsp;</textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Link" />
        <input type="hidden" name="link_hidden" value="1"><br />
            <div class="loader"><img class="loading-image" src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
            <div class="response" id="addNoteResponse"></div>
        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

The problem is that after my AJAX code completes, it updates the DIV as expected but make the modal automatically disappears yet my browser window still has the opacity overlay. If I then click anywhere in the browser window, the opacity goes away. But I would still like to have the modal visible so the user can choose to close it maually or submit more data.

If I remove this code, the modal plugin functions normally.

```
$("##noteDiv").load( 'templates/dashboard_notes.cfm?techID=#techID#' );
```

Any ideas?

Here is my complete AJAX code:

```
<!---Script to add dashboard link --->     
        <cfoutput>
        <script>
        $(function(){
        //Add a new note to a link
        $("##add_dashboard_links").submit(function(){
           // prevent native form submission here
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('##add_dashboard_links').serialize(),
                    url: "actionpages/add_dashboard_link.cfm",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('.loader').show();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                         $('.loader').hide(3000);
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        $("##noteDiv").load( 'templates/dashboard_notes.cfm?techID=#techID#' );
                        $("##addNoteResponse").html('');
                        $("##link_description").val('');
                        $("##link_url").val('');
                        $("##notes").val('');
                        $("##addNoteResponse").append( "Link successfully added." );
                      }    
                });
                return false;           
            });
        });
      </script>
      </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to a solution to this issue by working with the developer of this plugin: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal/issues/89